# Float data loss and precision issue

Tags: java, floating-point

```
String abc=11235.271;
Float.parsefloat(abc);
```

o/p 11235.271 no data loss

while as in

```
String abc=58996.706;
Float.parsefloat(abc);
```

o/p 58996.707

.001 is getting added after decimal

Can anyone pls help me on this

Comment: Simply, float is less precize than decimal. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net

Answer (score 0):

consider using a double or bigDecimal:

```
String abc2 = "58996.706";
System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(abc2));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(abc2));
```